# using chrome.windows.create() to launch a window in PWA mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps

I'd like to use my chrome extension to create and manage the focus for windows in my Progressive Web App. Focusing windows works well, but whenever I try to create a new window using `chrome.windows.create()`, the url loads into a new web browser window and not within the PWA.  Is there a way to get chrome to recognize that a url within that scope should always load within the PWA?

My app requires allowing the user to micromanage their window focus to keep their workflow fast, and unfortunately vanilla `.open()` and `.focus()` have loads of limitations within chrome.

Comment: You want to open multiple instances of the same PWA?

Comment: Use chrome.management.launchApp(id) with the pwa's id which you can see via chrome.management.getAll(console.log)

Comment: Why not just try to open the URL of your PWA? If it is installed, Chrome will open the standalone PWA for you.